# SPA javascript configuration file

Tags: javascript, .net, configuration

I have a SPA (single page application) build entirely in Javascript/ HTML /CSS. No other language used. Now I have lots of configuration data for the application. Which can be group specific. For example Set A group connect to different IP for Ajax then Set B group. etc etc

For that I want to have a single configuration file from all these configuration can be accessed.

One approach would be to make a javascript file containing all these configuration. My SPA application will read configuration from this Javascript file.

```
Pros: No new mechanism to be added to read configuration file
Cons: For every config change I have to change the code from the deployed live website.
```

The second approach would be to make a web service in let say .net and my application will read all the configuration from this web service whenever it loads.

```
Pros: Separate configuration file mechanism using standard place to store configuration data
Cons: introduce new mechanism/ language only for configuration data only.
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to read configuration data from javascript. Or which of the above mentioned approach would be more robust and work in long run

Comment: Hope you are using backbone.js for your SPA!  I can't imagine that your SPA is not already talking to a backend technology somewhere (even if it is to node.js server still in javascript).  My recommendation is to go with the web service approach -- being able to change the configuration without downtime to your SPA would be nice feature IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a different JS file at the server for each group?  Format the configuration data in JSON and store it in the file.  You could even create an admin tool that generates new config files to make it easy to manage group configurations.  Export the file to JSON and give it a name like `groupAConfig.js`.